# How to get content of external resources on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, webkit, adblock

I'm developing a chrome plugin, similar to adblock and I'm trying to figure out how to get access to the resources being loaded on a particular page.

For example, if a page is loading an external javascript or an iframe that has some specific strings - I'd like to intercept it.

How can I see the source of these external resources? Can I use Javascript/JQuery for that or I need to use Webkit's functions?

Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, this is actually a non-trivial thing. Using `webRequest` API, you can at most get to the response headers.

Comment: If you want to control loading in real time, you can look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You need to inject code with it to page (add <script> to DOM) from content script. If you do it on document_start, you will be able to control load of any script file